# Gem for Finding Associated University of Email Addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, rubygems

I don't think this exists, but I thought I should ask before reverting to finding some CSV table with this data. I receive a college email from the user and I want to find the name of the University that is associated with the suffix of the email. For example, `jason@uga.edu` should be associated to `University of Georgia`. Is there some Rails gem that could help me solve my dilemma or am I going to have to create some database or hash with this data?

Comment: I don't know about a gem, but here is a list of domains belonging to US universities: http://doors.stanford.edu/universities.html

Couldn't find an international list, though :(

Comment: Unfortunately the list doesn't list all universities in the United States.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably hack something together with: https://github.com/weppos/whois.

```
require 'whois'

r = Whois.whois("uga.edu")
r.registrant_contact.organization # => "University of Georgia"
```

If you have considerable amount of traffic, think about a caching mechanism that'll store the WHOIS information, so you don't have to ask the WHOIS server for each and every request.

Comment: I'll look into it. If it works for what I need I'll give you credit.